# Upgrade Vista 32-Bit to Windows 7 64-Bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

Does any one have a way to upgrade Windows Vista 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 11):

There is no upgrade path from 32-bit to 64-bit that doesn't involve a format and reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

As previously mentioned, the only way to make the upgrade is to do a full reinstall by booting from the CD. Although using [Windows Easy Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Easy_Transfer) should make the process of maintaining files and settings trivial.

Comment: Does Windows Easy Transfer support moving settings from 32-bit to 64-bit? Think a friend of mine said it wasn't supported or something... would be nice if it did though.

Comment: The only things that aren't migrated are simple display settings, they are listed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929459

Comment: Windows Files & settings transfer *won't* move settings from Win 7 x64 to 32 bit. It tells you so. I don't recall having problems going from 32 - 64 bit but that's not to say I've actually done it. Too old, don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend a clean install.  There is a lot of bloat that accumulates over time that causes Windows to slow down, and the only real way to reset it is to do a clean install, then re-install all of your applications.  I am working on my re-install list of programs so I don't forget anything essential when I go through this process.